# Why does my while loop output an out-of-bounds value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

So I was doing while loops and I noticed something strange.

```
count = 0

while count <= 5:
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

it's not that I don't understand while loops. It's that how come the count is printed up to six? when it's supposed to print `count` only if `count` is less than or equal to 5?

and well 6 is beyond 5. why is this?

I know I could do

```
count = 0

    while count != 5:
        count += 1
        print(count)
```

but I just want to understand why does putting `<=` behave in an odd way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing odd about `<=`; your loop condition allows for numbers up to *and including* `5`. But you increment `count` and *then* print it, so you will print `6` last.

That's because `count = 5` satisfies your loop condition, then you add one to make it `6` and print. The next time through the loop `count <= 5` is no longer true and only *then* loop ends.

So your code does this:

1. `count = 0`, `count <= 5` -> `True`, `count += 1` makes `count = 1`, print `1`.
2. `count = 1`, `count <= 5` -> `True`, `count += 1` makes `count = 2`, print `2`.
3. `count = 2`, `count <= 5` -> `True`, `count += 1` makes `count = 3`, print `3`.
4. `count = 3`, `count <= 5` -> `True`, `count += 1` makes `count = 4`, print `4`.
5. `count = 4`, `count <= 5` -> `True`, `count += 1` makes `count = 5`, print `5`.
6. `count = 5`, `count <= 5` -> `True`, `count += 1` makes `count = 6`, print `6`.
7. `count = 6`, `count <= 5` -> `False`, end the loop.

You could increment the counter *after* printing:

```
while count <= 5:
    print(count)
    count += 1
```

or you could use `<` to only allow numbers *smaller* than `5`:

```
while count < 5:
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

Comment: In other words, you will get a different result if you were to print before the increment.

Comment: I got it now. it stills increments count even if count is 5 because I used `<=` thats why 6 was outputted also because i put `count += 1` first so when the count was 5 it got added one then it checked the loop again it turns false so it breaks.

thanks for the visualization of what's happening!

Answer (score 3):

Let's walk through the code and see what's happening.

Note: If your code is doing something that you didn't expect it to do, this is a good practice to follow.

```
count = 0

while count <= 5:
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

The `count` starts at 0

```
count = 0

while count <= 5: # count = 0. Is 0 <= 5? Yes. Run the code.
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

Increment the count so it now equals 1. Print it.

```
while count <= 5: # count = 1. Is 1 <= 5? Yes. Run the code.
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

Increment. Print. Repeat.

Let's move on to the interesting case that's causing the problem.

```
while count <= 5: # count = 5. Is 5 <= 5? Yes. Run the code.
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

In this case the `count` still satisfies the inequality, so the code runs.

What happens?

The `count`, which is 5, is incremented and thus prints out 6.

---

Now that I hope you understand why the problem exists, let's explore alternatives and their advantages, disadvantages, and outputs.

---

Let's start with your code.

```
count = 0

while count <= 5:
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

Advantages: Does not print out 0

Disadvantages: Prints out 6

---

What if we removed the `=` sign?

```
count = 0

while count < 5:
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Advantages: Does what you want

Disadvantages: You have to start at 0 instead of 1

---

What if we did as you suggested and replaced the `<` sign with the `!` sign?

```
count = 0

while count != 5:
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Advantages: Does what you want

Disadvantages: Fragile. If you ever changed your increment so that it increased by a number like, say, 3, the end point would be skipped over accidentally and the code would continue to run forever. Better to use an inequality

---

What if we wanted where we start to be the first number that is displayed? Well, to do this we'd have to print out the current number before we change it, so that means we have to flip the order of the events.

```
count = 1 # Change the first number so it's what we want displayed first.

while count <= 5:
    print(count)
    count += 1
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Advantages: Does what you want and starts on the first displayed number instead of below it.

Disadvantages: If you want to stick with `while` loops, this is the way to go, but there is a better way in this case.

---

In situations like this, where you increment numbers and then perform operations with them, it's much more logical to just use a [`for` loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop), which was designed for instances just like this one.

```
for count in range(1,5):
    print(count)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Advantages: Does what you want, easier to read, easier to write, less likely to cause bugs based on placement.

Disadvantages: The upper boundary must be known, unlike in a `while` loop.

Comment: The output of
```
for count in range(1,5):
    print(count)
``` 
is not 1 2 3 4 5. It's 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 2):

It is simple when count equals five you add 1 and it becomes 6 then it is printed and you exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not about how `<=` works.

You are adding 1 to `count` before printing it, so when count is equal to 5, you then add 1 and therefore print 6.

Answer (score 0):

## To make things clear i will show the two scenarios with concrete explanation:

```
a=0
while (a<4):
  a=a+1
  print(a)
```

output would be 1,2,3,4

Variable a=0 should satisfy the condition(a<4) of while loop to continue the execution.

a=a+1 is calculated and saved in memory of the loop which is now 1.
Therefore the number 1 would be outputted not 0 as a result of print(a).
In order to iterate again inside the loop; the number 1(that was saved in the memory of the first loop is checked against the a<4 condition). Which is True; continue execution as previous.

a=a+1 calculated and saved in memory of loop which is now 2.
Then the number 2 is outputted
and is saved in the memory of the second loop and checked afterwards against the a<4). Which is True; continue execution as previous.

a=a+1 calculated and saved in memory of loop which is now 3.
Then the number 3 is outputted
and is saved in the memory of the third loop which is checked afterwards against the a<4). Which is True; continue execution as previous.

a=a+1 calculated and saved in memory of loop which is now 4.
Then the number 4 is outputted, even though the condition a<4 should be satisfied. The reason is that, i have stuck inside the loop after satisfaction of previous condition 3<4 and now after i am inside the loop, the execution of the statements is inevitable which will hold to output 4. The number 4 is now saved in the memory of the fourth loop which is checked against the a<4). Which is False, execution stop here.

This scenario would be amenable and understandable to the case of the opposite scenario

```
a=0
while (a<4):
  print(a)
  a=a+1
```

Output would be 0,1,2,3

Variable a=0 should satisfy the condition(a<4) of while loop to continue the execution.

First the print statement is executed, and the first value coined by a in the memory of the first loop is 0. Therefore 0 is outputted.
Afterwards a=a+1 is calculated and saved in memory of the loop which will change to be 1 and not 0.
In order to iterate again inside the loop; the number 1(that was saved in the memory of the first loop is checked against the a<4 condition). Which is True; continue execution as previous.

The print statement is executed, and the value coined by a in the memory of the second loop is now 1. Therefore 1 is outputted.
Afterwards a=a+1 is calculated and saved in memory of the loop which is now 2.
In order to iterate again inside the loop; the number 2(that was saved in the memory of the second loop is checked against the a<4 condition). Which is True; continue execution as previous.

The print statement is executed, and the value coined by a in the memory of the third loop is now 2. Therefore 2 is outputted.
Afterwards a=a+1 is calculated and saved in memory of the loop which is now 3.
In order to iterate again inside the loop; the number 3(that was saved in the memory of the third loop is checked against the a<4 condition). Which is True; continue execution as previous.

First the print statement is executed, and the value coined by a in the memory of the fourth loop is now 3. Therefore 3 is outputted.
Afterwards a=a+1 is calculated and saved in memory of the loop which is now 4.
In order to iterate again inside the loop; the number 4(that was saved in the memory of the fourth loop is checked against the a<4 condition). Which is False; execution stops.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

Many beginners have difficulty with this problem conceptually. They often expect the loop to exit as soon as the condition is met, even in the middle of an iteration.

*It does not work that way*. The `while` loop condition is [**only** checked at the **beginning** of each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65367298/python-while-loop-breakout-issues). It is the same as how an `if` block works - if the condition is met at the beginning, the rest of the block will be run, even if the condition stops being met.

If you want to exit a loop partway through an iteration, `break` can do that. However, *you need to check the condition again* in order for it to matter. Also keep in mind that you are writing a condition to *leave* the loop, rather than a condition to *stay*; so the logic needs to be reversed.

A lot of the time, it is easier to write code logic that checks a condition *only* partway through, and use an unconditional loop. That looks like (admittedly this is a silly example):

```py
while True:
    count += 1
    if count > 5:
        break
    print(count)
```

In Python 3.8 and above, it is *sometimes* possible to simplify that sort of code using the so-called "walrus" operator, which [assigns a value but also creates an expression rather than a statement](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) (like how `=` works in C and C++):

```
count = 0
while (count := count + 1) <= 5:
    print(count)
```

(Note that we cannot use `:+=` or `+:=` to avoid repeating `count`; those simply don't exist.)