# Python While loop breakout issues

Tags: python, while-loop, flags

The question I have is about the flag I have here for the while loop. This works but not like I think it should. I assume I'm not understanding something so if someone is able to explain, that would be great.

From my understanding this should break out of the loop as soon as one of my conditionals is met. So if I input 'q' it should break out and stop the loop. But what happens is it keeps going through the loop and then it breaks out. so it goes through the last prompt and prints the exception.

(Python version is 3.8.5)

```
# Statement that tells the user what we need.
print("Enter two numbers and I will tell you the sum of the numbers.")
# Lets the user know they can press 'q' to exit the program.
print("Press 'q' at anytime to exit.")

keep_going = True

# Loop to make the program keep going until its told to stop.
while keep_going:
    # Prompt for user to input first number and store it in a variable.
    first_number = input("First number: ")
    # Create a break when entering the first number.
    if first_number == 'q':
        keep_going = False
    # Prompt for user to input second number and store it in a variable.
    second_number = input("Second number: ")
    # Create a break when entering the second number.
    if second_number == 'q':
        keep_going = False
    # Exception for non integers being input "ValueError"
    try:
        # Convert input to integers and add them. 
        # storing the answer in a variable.
        answer = int(first_number) + int(second_number)
    except ValueError:
        # Tell the user what they did wrong.
        print("Please enter a number!")
    else:    
        # Print the sum of the numbers
        print(f"\nThe answer is: {answer}")
```

Using this code it breaks out right away like I expect it to.

```
while True:
    first_number = input("First number: ")
    if first_number == 'q':
        break
    second_number = input("Second number: ")
    if second_number == 'q':
        break
```

I just would like to understand what the difference is and if thats how it should work. I feel like I'm missing something or misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The condition of the `while` loop is only checked between iterations of the loop body, so if you change the condition in the middle of the loop, the current iteration will finish before the loop terminates.  If you want to break a loop *immediately*, you need to either `break` (which automatically breaks the loop regardless of the condition) or `continue` (which jumps to the next iteration, and will therefore terminate the loop if the condition is no longer true).

Using `while True:` with a `break` when you want to stop the loop is generally much more straightforward than trying to control the loop by setting and unsetting a flag.

FWIW, rather than copying and pasting the code to input the two numbers, and have two different ways to break out of the loop, I might put that all into a function and break the loop with an `Exception`, like this:

```
print("Enter two numbers and I will tell you the sum of the numbers.")
print("Press 'q' at anytime to exit.")


def input_number(prompt: str) -> int:
    """Ask the user to input a number, re-prompting on invalid input.
    Exception: raise EOFError if the user enters 'q'."""
    while True:
        try:
            number = input(f"{prompt} number: ")
            if number == 'q':
                raise EOFError
            return int(number)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number!")


while True:
    try:
        numbers = (input_number(n) for n in ("First", "Second"))
        print(f"The answer is: {sum(numbers)}")
    except EOFError:
        break
```

This makes it easier to extend the program to handle more than two inputs; try adding a "Third" after where it says "First" and "Second"!  :)

Comment: Awesome, Thank you! That explains it perfectly. I was misunderstanding how the loop interacts with the flag. Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 5):

Once you run the program and type "q", Yes indeed `keep_going` will be set to `False` but it **DOES NOT MEAN** it will break the loop already, it will just make the `keep_going` be equal to `False` thus on the **NEXT ITERATION** will stop the loop. Why is that? because it would be like this `while keep_going:` -> `while False:` so since it is not `True` thus not executing the program anymore.

Now based on your goal as you mentioned. You can do it this way where you can add the `break`.

```
if first_number == 'q':
    keep_going = False
    break
# Prompt for user to input second number and store it in a variable.
second_number = input("Second number: ")
# Create a break when entering the second number.
if second_number == 'q':
    keep_going = False
    break
```

I'd also like to suggest have it this way, it's just more specific in terms of what is to happen on the code, but of course it is up to you.

```
first_number = input("First number: ")
# Create a break when entering the first number.
if first_number == 'q':
    keep_going = False
    break
# Prompt for user to input second number and store it in a variable.
# Create a break when entering the second number.
else:
    second_number = input("Second number: ")
    if second_number =='q':
        keep_going = False
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

**While loops execute until their given condition is false.** A loop will only check its condition when required (program execution is moved to the top of the loop). In almost every case, this occurs when the full body of the loop has run. See here:

```py
keep_going = True

while keep_going:
  keep_going = False
  # keep_going is False, but this will still print once
  # because the loop has not checked its condition again.
  print("Will execute once")
```

*"Will execute once"* prints a single time even after `keep_going` is set to False. This happens because the while loop does not re-check its condition until its entire body has run.

**However, `break` statements are different.** A `break` statement will cause a loop to exit immediately no matter what.

```py
keep_going = True

while keep_going:
  break # Exits the while loop immediately. The condition is not checked.
  print("Will never print")
```

Here, nothing is printed even though `keep_going` is `True` the whole time. `break` made the loop exit regardless of the condition.

**A `continue` statement will move program execution back to the start of the loop, and cause your condition to be checked again.**

In this example, `continue` sends program execution back to the start of the loop. Since `keep_going` was set to `False`, nothing will print because the while loop will exit after realizing its condition evaluates to false.

```py
keep_going = True

while keep_going:
  keep_going = False
  continue
  print("Will never print")
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, hope you have a great time learning Python!

Both ways will work and stop the loop, but there is a difference:

1. In the first method, you are changing the `keep_going` variable to false, therefore, the loop will stop when the the `while` loops finds out that `keep_going` had become `False`. However, the checking only happens at the end of the loop (In your case, it is after you have done your `except` or `else` part), the loop will not stop right away even when you entered `q` for your variable `first_number`.
2. In the second solution, you are using the `break` keyword in Python, to break away from the loop right away after you entered `q` for `first_number`.

Technically speaking, you will want to `break` if you want to break off from the loop right away when `q` is detected, otherwise, setting `keep_going` to `False` if you want the whole loop to be completed, but not run again for the next round.

In scenario 1 the result, even when you entered `q`,

```
Please enter a number!
```

Will always show, but not for scenario 2.

Answer (score 1):

this is a little different approach to your script:

```
def main():
    print("Enter two numbers and I will tell you the sum of the numbers.")
    print("Press 'q' at anytime to exit.")
    val = []
    while True:

        check_value = lambda x: 'quit' if x.lower() == 'q' or x.lower() == 'quit' else int(x)
        if not val:
            value = input("First number: ")
        elif len(val) == 2:
            answer = sum(val)
            print(f"\nThe answer is: {answer}")
            print('==='*15 + ' < ' + f'PROGRAM RESTARTING' + ' > ' + '==='*15)

            val[:] = []
            continue
        else:
            value = input("Second number: ")


        try:
            check_ = check_value(value)
            val.append(check_)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number!")
            continue
        finally:
            if check_ == 'quit':
                print('Program is stopping....')
                break
            else:
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It check at anytime the user's input, whether is a 'q' 'Q' or ('quit' or 'QUIT') or any combination or capital letter because run the check `x.lower()`

I suggest you to have a look at [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/#the-python-break-and-continue-statements) especially the paragraph "he Python break and continue Statements."

Long story short:

- Use `Break` to terminate the loop at any given time.
- Use `continue` to roll back where you left and repeat the loop again (I used it in my code if the value is not a Int)
- User `pass` to keep the loop running with no stop.